# Navigating to part of a div after unhiding

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How would I navigate to a part of a div that was hidden and then uncovered by setting `display:block` on it?

I've tried saving the position I want to get to and using `document.location.scrollTop` as well as calling `scrollTo(`) on the specific element within the div. Since the div is already loaded I think it tries to execute the code right away before the page get fully re-rendered.

A more or less functional bare-bones example of the page:
There is a few caveats in the production code like an animate transition in the toggle ( could be the problem actually).

After calling the navigate/transition function I do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script> function swapper(id){
document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'none'; 
document.getElementById('detail').innerHTML = 'some details about ' + id;       document.getElementById('detail').style.display = 'block';
} </script>
</head>        
 <body>
     <button id="backbutton" onclick="document.getElementById('list').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('detail').style.display = 'none';">Back</button>                
       <div id="list" style="display:block;">
             <ul>
                   <li id="1" onclick=swapper(1)>1</li>
                   <li id="2" onclick=swapper(2)>2</li>
             </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="detail" style="display:none;"></div>
 </body>
```

​

Comment: Do you have some code you can share with us? I don"t understand what you mean by "part of a div"? How big is this DIV? What is the content of this DIV? What is around the DIV? etc...

Comment: if you could use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a demo, that would help us a log :)

Comment: Hey, sorry I kept the question light because I attempted to ask it a few days ago with a lot more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907762/navigating-to-specific-element-on-a-virtual-sub-page
give me a second to write up a more fully functional jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Whatever triggers the setting display:block, should then sequentially trigger a scroll to that new visisble div.

Comment: The display:block toggle adds/removes classes and animates the swap with some webkit transition logic. Ive tried just calling scrolling functions just after it but it doesnt seem to have any effect. Calling the functions in console after the page is fully rendered on my screen works fine. So the problem seems to be the fact that the div isnt fully rendered at the time of the call.